# Electron Capture or K-Capture and Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle

Tags: general-relativity, electrons, speed-of-light, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, radioactivity

I read about Electron Capture or K-Capture in radioactivity. There I found that the electron in the K shell is captured by the nucleus and as a result the atomic number of the element decreases by 1 unit.
But by Heisenberg's-Uncertainty-principle states that electron cannot fall into the nucleus because it's speed will exceed speed of light. So how it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electrons are not in fixed obits around the nucleus, the Bohr model is a semi-classical model of the real quantum mechanical solutions. The electrons are in orbitals, probability loci. Have a look , for simplicity, of [the orbitals of the energy levels](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) available to the electron of the hydrogen atom.

[image: orbitals]

Note that there is a probability for s orbitals for the electron to overlap the nucleus. electron orbitals  in the K shell have a higher probability of overlapping with the nucleus .

This does not defy the Heisenberg uncertainty,  which is an envelope that covers the possibility of measuring two variables at the same time.like position and momentum. There is no measurement when an electron orbital gives a probability for the electron to be in the nucleus, and thus allow it to further interact with the nucleons.